# MapFish Print: does it support ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, cartography, printing, mapfish

we are looking for a map print solution, MapFish printing module quite fits. but as far as the searches I've done, it seems MapFish doesn't support ArcGIS Server. One thing I am not sure about is, whether it supports ArcGIS Server WMS or not?

wish someone in this site who knows this can give me some advice. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead look at the readers.  Since WMS and WMTS are supported why not an AGS services which publish one of these protocols?

- GoogleMapReader
- GoogleMapTileReader
- ImageMapReader
- MapServerMapReader
- OsmMapReader
- TileCacheMapReader
- TmsMapReader
- VectorMapReader
- WMSMapReader
- WMTSMapReader

But just to be certain I put a test together.  I had to modify config.yaml to add my ArcGIS Server to the hosts:

```
#==========================
# the list of allowed hosts
#==========================
hosts:
  - !dnsMatch
    host: myags10host
    port: 6080
```

And I modified the PrintPreview.js (from the GeoExt.ux PrintPreview example) in the following way:

```
mapPanel = new GeoExt.MapPanel({
    region: "center",
    map: {
        maxExtent: bounds,
        maxResolution: 0.018140625,
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        units: 'degrees'
    },
    layers: [
    new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("ESRI WMS Vegas",
        "http://myags10host:6080/arcgis/services/Vegas/DevVegas3857DynamicOnly/MapServer/WMSServer",
        { layers: "3" },
        { singleTile: true, numZoomLevels: 8 })],
    extent: bounds,
    bbar: [{
        text: "Print...",
        handler: showPrintWindow
    }]
});
```

And it did in fact produce a PDF file:
[image: MapFishPrintAgsWMS]

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to support it:

```
mapfish.PrintProtocol.SUPPORTED_TYPES = {
479     'OpenLayers.Layer': mapfish.PrintProtocol.IGNORED,
480     'OpenLayers.Layer.WMS': mapfish.PrintProtocol.prototype.convertWMSLayer,
481     'OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.Untiled': mapfish.PrintProtocol.prototype.convertWMSLayer,
482     'OpenLayers.Layer.TileCache': mapfish.PrintProtocol.prototype.convertTileCacheLayer
```

http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/browser/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/core/PrintProtocol.js?rev=1216

But could be added if have the right skills

Comment: yes. i checked this protocol file before.. I am still not sure about MapFish's capabilities in terms of data source support. maybe I have to set up a demo site to test them out by myself.. thank you, but i am not sure whether this is the answer for now..

Comment: It does support it but not /export or /tile access...just WMS and now WMTS.